# replace a column with a column's value in another table in MySQL select

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in a database with these sample data:

**listings table:**

`listings.locations_L1`: 'province_far_shiraz'

**lang_keys table:**

`lang_keys.Key`: 'data_formats+name+province_far_shiraz'

`lang_keys.Value`: 'Shiraz City'

---

I want to select from table `listings` and replace values of column `listings.locations_L1` with `lang_keys.Value` in result.

Note that string `data_formats+name+` is concatinated to all records of table lang_keys, column `Value`.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it would be to join the tables based on comparing to `Key` to a concatenation `data_formats+name+` to `listings`.`locations_L1` in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM `listings`
INNER JOIN `lang_keys` ON 
  `lang_keys`.`Key` = CONCAT('data_formats+name+', `listings`.`locations_L1`)
```